# Multiple CSS transitions

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am having a problem getting two transitions to work together.

The second animation works (partially) but swing effect seems to reset and stop repeating after a while and the first animation doesn't work at all.

This is my animation code:

```
.box{
    width:250px; height:50px;
    background:blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
    top:0px;

    animation-name: fall;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;

    animation-name: swing;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinte;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
@-moz-keyframes fall{
   from {top: -50px;}   
    to {top: 0px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fall{
   from {top: -50px;}   
    to {top: 0px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes swing{
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(-2deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    -webkit-transform-origin:center top;
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

Demo can be found here with the problem shown: **http://jsfiddle.net/akwbmw86/**

What am i getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing browser specific prefixes with no browser specific prefixes, also to specify multiple animations you just need to separate them with a commma. In you example the fall animation is overwritten by the swing animation.

Something like this:

```
.box{
    width:250px; height:50px;
    background:blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
    top:150px;

    animation: fall 1.5s ease-in, swing 4s  ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fall 1.5s ease-in, swing 4s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fall 1.5s ease-in, swing 4s  ease-in-out;
}

@-moz-keyframes fall{
   0% {top: -50px;} 
   100% {top: 150px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fall{
   0% {top: -50px;} 
   100% {top: 150px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes swing{
    -moz-transform-origin: center top;
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(-2deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    -webkit-transform-origin:center top;
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akwbmw86/1/)

Comment: This makes any animation tied to a hover - no longer work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hjgLbry0/ so how would something trigger based transitions work with this kind of format style?

Comment: @Dave where did you see hover? When I open my fiddle the block falls down. Sorry I am not sure what exactly you're asking. Do you want the block to fall when you hover over it?

Comment: i added a hover transition to see how it would work, but it seems once you have two or more key frames, the hover won't work. I don't know the syntax to apply it to a mouse hover using the syntax you used. Also i don't know why but i cannot @ your username in the comments.